# Javascript inserted doesn't show up when called from updatepanel event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

Any clues why the button click event doesn't insert script succesfully?

Here is the really straightforward code.

C#:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "scriptalert", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('testLOAD');</script>;", false);
        btnAdd.Click += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Clicked);
}

protected void btnAdd_Clicked(Object sender,System.EventArgs e){
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "scriptfunc", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">func();</script>;", false);
}
```

}

HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("testSCRIPT");

function func() {
    alert("testFUNC");
}
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div id="View" style="height: 50%; width:20%; ">
        blahblahblah
    </div>
    <div id="Addd" style="height: 50%; width:100%;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateAdd" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

On page load I get two alerts firing, namely "testLOAD" and "testSCRIPT", but when  I press the button nothing happens (there is supposed to be a third alert)...  Checked in debugger, the event is called and runs, but when I view page source nothing was inserted.

I have a suspicion that the problem might lie elsewhere, since copy-pasting this into a new page without a master page (i.e. without ASP:Content tags) works. I haven't had any problems with other script insertions though, so why this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong ^.^

There was a stray semicolon inside the script i was inserting, which made it break :/

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "scriptfunc", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">func();</script>;", false);
```

Such a silly error caused so much frustration... sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from having the button inside the update panel. To overcome this problem, I think you can use ScriptManager instead of ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method. Something like the following should do it;

```
ToolkitScriptManager1.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "<script type=\"text/javascript\">func();</script>;", true);
```

instead of

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "scriptfunc", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">func();</script>;", false);
```

Comment: I have another page where this works fine inside an update panel  Tried that code, it says 'RegisterStartupScript' cannot be called from an instance, I think it is a static method.  using 'ScriptManager' instead of 'ClientScript' doesn't fix the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

string script ="alert('something');";

this.ClientScript.registerclientscriptblock(this.GetType(), "scriptfunc", script, true);

or place your function inside the page_load event and call the function in the Button.OnClientClick  property.

Comment: using OnClientClick isn't useful in this case, since I want to run stuff in the code behind and THEN do the javascript.
although it does call the function that way, javascript would run before I want it to.